# jQuery - need assistance - mousemove event

Tags: jquery, mouseevent

how are you guys?

i am a complete beginner in jQuery, and i'm using  `mousemove`  event on parent element, and i am fading in a `div` based on `cursor's position`, but the problem i am facing is, when that `child div` appears, and i am hovering that `child div` the `mousemove` does not fire, while it fires for every other child.
any help is appreciated.

HTML Code:

```
<table class="maintable">

<div class="large"></div>

    <tr>
        <td >

            <img class="enlargeimg" src="" />

        </td >
    </tr>

</table>
```

CSS:

```
* {margin: 0; padding: 0;}

.maintable {width: 400px; height:400px; 
margin: 50px auto; 
position: relative; 
background-color: blue; padding: 30px;}

.large {
    width: 175px; height: 175px;
    position: absolute;

    z-index:5;

    box-shadow: 0 0 0 7px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.85), 
    0 0 7px 7px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25), 
    inset 0 0 40px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);





    display: none;
}

.maintable img { width:200px; height: 200px; display: block; background-color: red; }
```

Jquery Code:

```
$('table.maintable').on('mousemove' , function(e){

$(".large").css({
        left: e.pageX - $(".large").width()/2,
        top: e.pageY  - $(".large").height()/2
}).fadeIn();

});
```

[**Here is a fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/gWP5x/26/)

Comment: I don't see the issue you are describing with the code you provided, can you please clarify? Or better, make a jsfiddle that demonstrates the issue?

Comment: The problem is, that fadeIn div element is jumping around, rather than moving smoothly, as mousemove is not being triggered when cursor is over that div.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the css property pointer-events. If you set it to none, then all your mouse events will be passed along to the underlying elements.

In your case, it would be added to the .large style:

```
.large {
    pointer-events:none;
}
```

For more information, check out https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events

Here is an updated fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/boleary/dnae98w1/